# How do I find the regular expression for- All binary numbers greater than 110011

Tags: regular-expressions, binary, lexical-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem set to practice for an exam. How can I approach questions like these ? Is there a way to verify solutions or is it just trial and error ?

Comment: Could you do it if asked to find all binary numbers greater than 1. How about all binary numbers greater than 10?

Comment: @RickDecker is it 1*01* ?

Comment: Don't guess. Try to think how these numbers look like.

Comment: It might be a trifle easier if instead you made a FA for the language.

Answer (score 2):

If a number is more than 6 bits long (not counting leading zeroes) then it is certainly larger than your number. Otherwise, it is one of finitely many numbers, preceded by an arbitrary number of leading zeroes.